# menustrip in a listview with the problems is the same from the same line and not the line that I think on

Tags: c#, listview

I have a problem is that it can only take one person at a time. If two persons are inside so you can only ban those who are in sympathy list. If I am self inside then everything works fine.

[image]

**Video: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2d17pm0%3E&s=8#.U9KnGfl_tvB**

### If I am self inside then everything works. But when it comes in more then you can only banned it as is sympathy in a row.

I need help to fix the code so that it works properly?
When I right-click a row and tries banned. Then try it banned me and not the line that I think on.

```
private void UserListUpdate(string rawdata)
    {
        var data = rawdata.Deserialize();
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var user in data)
        {
            var attr = user.Deserialize();
            string nick = attr[0];
            string role = attr[1];
            bool isbanned = attr[2].ToLower() == "true";
            string userid = attr[3];
            string isbannedText = "";
            var ban = new MenuItem("Ban", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(userid, "banned")));
            var unban = new MenuItem("Unban", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(userid, "unbanned")));
            var admin = new MenuItem("Admin", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(userid, Sets.UserRole.Admin)));
            var reg = new MenuItem("Regularize", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(userid, Sets.UserRole.Regular)));
            var kill = new MenuItem("Kill", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.Kill(userid)));
            mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Clear();
            mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(new[] { admin, reg, GetSep(), ban, unban, GetSep(), kill });
            ListViewItem t = new ListViewItem(nick);
            if(isbanned == true)
            {
                isbannedText = "Bannad";
            }
            t.SubItems.Add(role);
            t.SubItems.Add(isbannedText);
            t.SubItems.Add(userid);
            listView1.Items.Add(t);
        }
    }

    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu;
        }
    }

    private MenuItem GetSep()
    {
        return new MenuItem("-");
    }
```

So I did but still it does not work.

```
private void UserListUpdate(string rawdata)
    {
        var data = rawdata.Deserialize();
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var user in data)
        {
            var attr = user.Deserialize();
            string nick = attr[0];
            string role = attr[1];
            bool isbanned = attr[2].ToLower() == "true";
            string userid = attr[3];
            string isbannedText = "";
            var ban = new MenuItem("Ban", BanMenu_Clicked);
            var unban = new MenuItem("Unban", BanMenu_Clicked);
            var admin = new MenuItem("Admin", BanMenu_Clicked);
            var reg = new MenuItem("Regularize", BanMenu_Clicked);
            var kill = new MenuItem("Kill", BanMenu_Clicked);
            mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Clear();
            mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(new[] { admin, reg, GetSep(), ban, unban, GetSep(), kill });
            ListViewItem t = new ListViewItem(nick);
            if(isbanned == true)
            {
                isbannedText = "Bannad";
            }
            t.SubItems.Add(role);
            t.SubItems.Add(isbannedText);
            t.SubItems.Add(userid);
            listView1.Items.Add(t);
        }
    }

    private void BanMenu_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.SelectedItems) {
          Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(li.SubItems[2].ToString(), "banned")));
        }
    }

    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu;
        }
    }

    private MenuItem GetSep()
    {
        return new MenuItem("-");
    }
```

---

Edit 2

```
private void UserListUpdate(string rawdata)
    {
        var data = rawdata.Deserialize();
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var user in data)
        {
            var attr = user.Deserialize();
            string nick = attr[0];
            string role = attr[1];
            bool isbanned = attr[2].ToLower() == "true";
            string userid = attr[3];
            string isbannedText = "";
            var ban = new MenuItem("Ban", BanMenu_Clicked);
            var unban = new MenuItem("Unban", UnBanMenu_Clicked);
            var admin = new MenuItem("Admin", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(userid, Sets.UserRole.Admin)));
            var reg = new MenuItem("Regularize", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(userid, Sets.UserRole.Regular)));
            var kill = new MenuItem("Kill", (a, b) => Client.WritePacket(Packets.Kill(userid)));
            mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Clear();
            mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(new[] { admin, reg, GetSep(), ban, unban, GetSep(), kill });
            ListViewItem t = new ListViewItem(nick);
            if(isbanned == true)
            {
                isbannedText = "Bannad";
            }
            t.SubItems.Add(role);
            t.SubItems.Add(isbannedText);
            t.SubItems.Add(userid);
            listView1.Items.Add(t);
        }
    }

    private void BanMenu_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.SelectedItems) {
            Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(li.SubItems[3].Text, "banned"));
            MessageBox.Show(li.SubItems[3].Text);
        }
    }

    private void UnBanMenu_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(li.SubItems[3].Text, "unbanned"));
            MessageBox.Show(li.SubItems[3].Text);
        }
    }

    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Point pt = listView1.PointToScreen(e.Location);
            //contextMenuStrip1.Show(pt);
            ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu;
            //MessageBox.Show("Jaa");
        }
    }

    private MenuItem GetSep()
    {
        return new MenuItem("-");
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How I can fix so that I can banned. Because if I try to banned Zoe and then becomes Julia banned and not Zoe. It does not take the correct row.

Comment: When I right-click a row and tries banned. Then try it banned me and not the line that I think on.

Comment: Viewing the video and you will understand the error.

Comment: You seem to be always referencing the same userid.  You are always clearing the menu system on every loop, so only the last loop wins.  You should probably check the SelectedItems property in your code *somewhere*.

Comment: LarsTech@ Can you help me to encode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the SelectedItems property in your ListView control to see which items are currently highlighted, and since your data can only be found in the ListView, you have to get the information back out of it.

Something like this:

```
var banMenu = new MenuItem("Ban", BanMenu_Clicked);

private void BanMenu_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.SelectedItems) {
    Client.WritePacket(Packets.UpdateRole(li.SubItems[2].ToString(), "banned")));
  }
}
```

Your `UserListUpdate` method is creating and then removing the menu items on every loop iteration.  You should probably only create those menu items once in the form's constructor.

Comment: Can you write more code? Should I put everything in it?

Comment: Will not it work anyway. Can you write the whole code? Thanks. Forgive me

Comment: @viktoriadarkrevil This code is pretty simple.  It's unclear to me where you are stuck, or why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have to update my post, you can check out what I've done wrong?

Comment: Nothing happens when I try to banned or unbannad.

Comment: @viktoriadarkrevil Is an item selected when you do that?

Comment: Yes it is. You see if I've done something wrong with the code? I write the code in the first post so you can check on it.

Comment: @viktoriadarkrevil You've ignored my advice in the last paragraph.  Put a debug break on the code and see what happens when you select the Banned menu.  Obviously, all of your menus are currently configured to change the items to "Banned".

Comment: Would get really happy if you could make all the code? I have try debug but can not see.

Comment: When I troubleshoot I get this out ListViewSubItem: {3} But I just want to get out 3

Comment: Remove li.SubItems[3].ToString()  |||| 
Add li.SubItems[3].Text

Comment: Check out the edit 2. It works like that. Do you know how to do so menu only shows when you right-click on it. For now, it is as if I right click then I get up menu where the heel.

Comment: @viktoriadarkrevil Get rid of your `listView1_MouseClick` code, just set the menu to the control: `listView1.ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu;`